# path finder for multidimensional array

Tags: python

I am trying to make a dungeon based game and was in the process of making a theoretical path finder, but whenever I run the program, it just prints the same coordinates(theoretical) that I entered in the 1st place. I'm a bit "new" to programming in general so I got stuck

```
import winsound
def main():
    snd = winsound.Beep
    a = input("Enter the x value for the entrance: ")
    b = input("Enter the y value for the entrance: ")
    entrance = [a, b]

    x = input("Enter the x value for the exit: ")
    y = input("Enter the y value for the exit: ")
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    exut = [x, y] #deliberatly placed exit misspelling as exit is a command
    done = False
    while done == False:
        if b > a:
            b = b - 1
        elif b < a:
            b = b + 1
        else:
            if a > x:
                a = a - 1
            elif a < x:
                a = a + 1
            else:
                done = True

    done2 = False
    while done2 == False:
        if b > y:
            b = b - 1
        elif b < y:
            b = b + 1
        else:
            snd(494, 250)
            snd(659, 400)
            print("done!")
            print(entrance)
            print(exut)
            entrance = [a, b]
            exut = [a, b]
            done2 = True
```

when I run it and put lets say 1 for x value of entrance, 2 for y value of entrance, 3 for x value of exut and 4 for y value of exut I get this result;

```
>>> main()
Enter the x value for the entrance: 1
Enter the y value for the entrance: 2
Enter the x value for the exit: 3
Enter the y value for the exit: 4
done!
['1', '2']
[3.0, 4.0]
>>>
```

I don't know why it does that so please can you help, it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, what should it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to convert to float since you only move in steps of one, so get rid of this code:

```
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
x = float(x)
y = float(y)
```

It's inconsistent because you are assigning `a` and `b` to `entrance` before converting to float, but assigning `x` and `y` to `exut` after converting. However you should add code to make sure that only integer values can be entered for `entrance` and `exut`.

In your first loop, you are comparing `b` to `a`, when it should be compared to `y` (because `y` is the target value of `b`):

```
 while done == False:
    if b > y:       # changed a to y here
        b = b - 1
    elif b < y:     # changed a to y here too
        b = b + 1
    else:
        if a > x:
            a = a - 1
        elif a < x:
            a = a + 1
        else:
            done = True
```

Also, you don't need the second loop because after the first loop finishes, `a` and `b` will already be set to `x` and `y`. So you can just print out your values.

You are printing out `entrance` and `exut`, but you aren't printing out the final values of `a` and `b`:

```
print("done!")
print(entrance)
print(exut)
print(a, b)  # print out a and b. they should be equal to exut
```

If you want to see the progress of your pathfinder you can add `print(a, b)` to your pathfinding loop:

```
 while done == False:
    print(a, b)
    if b > y:       # changed a to y here
        b = b - 1
    elif b < y:     # changed a to y here too
        b = b + 1
    else:
        if a > x:
            a = a - 1
        elif a < x:
            a = a + 1
        else:
            done = True
```